# How to insert square bracket in itemize environment in LaTeX?

Tags: itemize, brackets

I insert square bracket in `itemize` environment in LaTeX, but there is an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item [$\left[ \frac{a}{b} \right] $ ]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How can I insert square bracket in itemize in LaTeX?

Comment: Just change `[` and `]` to `{[}` and `{]}`, respectively.

Comment: @Mico May you tell me why I should do that?

Comment: So that the square brackets print as square brackets. I thought that that was what you're trying to achieve. Pleaese advise if I misunderstool you objective.

Comment: @Mico  What you said is what I wanted to do. I find that in equation environment in LaTeX, we should use `\left[ \right]`, so why shouldn't I use it here?

Comment: @Y.zeng No, you don't *need* `\left[` and `\right]` in math mode. Sometimes it is useful, but definitely *not always*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use `$[\frac{a}{b}]$` as the item marker, you need to protect the closing `]` so it is not mistaken as the one closing the optional argument to `\item`. Additional braces suffice.

```
\item[{$[\frac{a}{b}]$}]
```

Alternatively

```
\item[$\lbrack\frac{a}{b}\rbrack$]
```

Comment: Why can't I use `\left[ \right]` here?

Comment: @Y.zeng You may use `\left` and `\right`, but they do no good in that case.